# Overwriting existing data to a line ending in a binary, c++

Tags: c++

I have a binary file that look like this (if it were line by line):-

```
3663322082 1 Production - Stop

3663327555 2 Production - Started

3663327645 0 Production - Run

3554422880 3 Waiting - Input from operator
```

Each part has an ending in hex of 070703.

I need to insert a new value, but overwrite the first line with my new value.  The problem I face is I can overwrite at the beginning of the file, but only up to the end of my new value.

I need to overwrite up to the end of the old value or replace the current(old) value with the new one.

So:-

```
3663322082 1 Production - Stop
```

would be replaced by:-

```
3663322745 0 Production - Run
```

and not

```
3663322745 0 Production - Runp
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your code that currently edits the file? It makes it easier to formulate a response

Comment: Is there a padding or value you can use that is ignored?